# stuck with secure boot enabled and nvidia driver

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04

when i enable secure boot, the boot stuck after the message clean disk, block size xxx.
my motherboard error code freeze at 27, which i search online saying this is a memory test that need to pass, but somehow it got stuck.

once i disable secure boot, everything starts to work properly. This is frankly very strange as it was working fine before this reboot..

searched online but basically found nothing. Does anyone else have similar experience or might know the reason of it?